# VIM) Overriding arrow keys on popup menu of 'You complete me' only works on 'down'

Tags: vim, plugins, key-bindings, keymapping, youcompleteme

Env: VIM 8.2.2815, PluginManager-Vundle

I installed YouCompleteMe Plugin for VIM. I use arrow keys a lot for moving between lines and characters. But YouCompleteMe popup hijack my arrow command so I decided to change key mapping.

First, I found that there is a default mapping for completion select like below. I added these lines to `~/.vimrc`

```
let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<TAB>', '<Up>']
let g:ycm_key_list_select_previous_completion = ['<S-TAB>', '<Down>']
```

So I removed `<Up>`, `<Down>`. But it doesn't work.
According to this link : https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues/2336, it might be a problem of VIM. So I added lines below to `~/.vimrc`

```
inoremap <expr> <up> pumvisible() ? '<c-y><up>' : '<up>'
inoremap <expr> <down> pumvisible() ? '<c-y><down>' : '<down>'
```

It worked. But only works on 'down' arrow, not on 'up'.
I have searched github YCM issues and google, but couldn't find any solution.

Is there any way to get it fixed?

edit)
I found out that arrow key has weird behavior. When `set showcmd` is on, hitting both `<Up>` and `<Down>` shows `~@k` on the right below of my vim. It can be a problem of mobaXterm or ssh, but not sure...